# Show last coordinate of a vector is positive

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, toeplitz-matrices

Let $T$ be a real symmetric Toeplitz matrix of dimension $n$. We write $T_i$ for the matrix with only the first $i$ rows and columns of $T$.

In my implementation of the [Levinson algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levinson_recursion) I'm building a family of backward vectors $(x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ such that
$$
x_1 = \left( \frac{1}{T_{11}} \right)
$$
and for $2 \leq i \leq n$
$$
x_i = \lambda_i
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{i-1, i-1} \\
\vdots \\
x_{i-1, 1} \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
+ \mu_i
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
x_{i-1, 1} \\
\vdots \\
x_{i-1, i-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $\lambda_i, \mu_i \in \mathbb{R}$.
We note that what Wikipedia calls forward vector is, here, the reverse of the backward one.
Also they have the property that
$$
T_i x_i =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
\vdots \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I want to show that the last coordinate of $x_i$ satisfy $x_{i, i} > 0$.
We easily see that
$$
x_{i,i} = \frac{1}{T_{11}} \prod_{k=2}^i \mu_k.
$$
I think I need to do an induction on the last equation but without directly knowing the $\mu_i$ it doesn't seem easy.
So I don't know where to start.